# JWrapper with Normal Uninstaller?

Tags: jwrapper

After a long weekend - I got JWrapper working with my application.

One thing I notice is that there are not uninstall entries in the Control Panel > Program and Features. ie:
[image]

I also noticed I had to write a custom app to place a short cut on the user's desktop. Not a problem, but this is something that is generally standard.

Is it possible to get the JWrapper installation to show up in the Program and Features (and whatever is equivelent for Macs)?

Answer (score 0):

JWrapper doesn't currently support installing to Programs and Features however it will by default install a program group into the start menu including an uninstaller shortcut.